$H^n(M,S;\Bbb R) = 0$ for $n$-manifold with nonempty boundary
The question is simple:

Let $M$ be a compact $n$-manifold with nonempty boundary and $S\subset M$ be an $n$-submanifold with nonempty boundary. Then $H^n(M,S;\Bbb R) = 0$.

I know that $H^n(M;\Bbb R) = 0 = H^n(S;\Bbb R)$ by the fact that both manifolds have nonempty boundaries. But it seems the statement is not an immediate consequence of these two. Is it true?

No, this is wrong as stated.

@MoisheKohan Even if I add orientability?

Yes, even then.

@MoisheKohan Why is that?

Work out an example.

Here is a counterexample. Assume in addition that $M$ is oriented and connected, and let $\partial M$ denote its boundary.
Let $S$ be a closed collar neighborhood of $\partial M$, so the pair $(M,S)$ is homotopy equivalent to $(M,\partial M)$ in the category of pairs. It follows that $H^n(M,S;\mathbb R) \approx H^n(M,\partial M;\mathbb R) \approx \mathbb R$ by Poincaré duality.
You could, in fact, take $S$ to be any compact $n$-dimensional submanifold of $M$ that contains $\partial M$, and then
$$H^n(M,S;\mathbb R) \approx H^M(\overline{M-S},\partial\overline{M-S};\mathbb R) \approx \mathbb R
$$
The second isomorphism is again Poincaré duality, but in this case the first isomorphism is an application of the excision theorem.

If $S$ is a proper submanifold of $\partial M$ so that the duality cannot be applied then... Hmm

If $S$ is a proper submanfold of $\partial M$ then $S$ is not $n$-dimensional so this is not an instance of your problem.

That's true but I meant I take a regular neighborhood of $S$ to thicken a bit but homotopy equivalent to the original one so essentially a proper submanifold of $\partial M$.
